# Interpolating missing data in time series in Python

Tags: python, time-series

I'm working with some data and I've got missing values. The data is your average time series: [image]

Here is a plot of 2016 only, where all the missing data is: [image]

Is there a way, using any Python library, to interpolate the missing data in a meaningful manner? Thanks

Comment: I'd say that's a range far to long (3 months) to make any kind of useful and sensible interpolation. In such a case is more like data-creation instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel you might very well be right. But this isn't random data, and as such, maybe it could be possible to fit a model to the rest of the data and use this model to interpolate the rest? Then again I won't do much with this data but produce graphs, so it's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Might produce somehow reasonable results, if there is seasonality in the series ans these are not just random spikes.

Comment: In R there is the 'imputeTS' package (package solely for time series imputation), which has some good methods like na.seadec() that might do a good job here. But I don't know familiar you are with R. You could use rpy2 to call R code from python.